# WebStorm removes HTML close tag after commit

Tags: angular, git, intellij-idea, webstorm

It seems that I make some wrong setting of WebStorm git commit. Now when I commit my code, WebStorm adds some double close tag `/>>` and removes the normal close tag in my Angular template files, like:

```html
<header-search [(toggleChange)]="searchToggleStatus"></header-search>
```

to

```html
<header-search [(toggleChange)]="searchToggleStatus />>
```

How to restore the normal setting?

Comment: I'ld recommend you take the easy way out on this one and just reset whichever plugin you use to default. I wouldn't say it is worth the time investment trying to understand what you've done to mess up those settings, especially when you (apparently) have no idea what you could have done. Might even be a version issue. Reset it, see if it persists.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at 'before commit' actions/pre-commit hooks you have configured to find a culprit